# How to pass digit or data from subclassed UIView to UIViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have subclassed UITableViewController and inside table I have custom cells. And this custom cells have subclassed UIView inside. So this UIView is written in its own class. In my code the UITableViewController class is named MainViewController.h/.m and UIView's class is named ContentView.h/.m So in ContentView I added an image and tapGestureRecognizer. To when the image is tapped some date(in this case digit) is send to MainViewController. The first problem is that the delegate method does not get called. And if I call it with notificationCenter it logged it as 0.00000 Can someone help me to pass data from view inside cell to ViewController.

This is my code:

ContentView.h:

```
@class ContentView;
@protocol ContentViewDelegate
- (void)passDigit:(float)someDigit;
@end

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MainViewController.h"

@interface ContentView : UIView
{
    id <ContentViewDelegate> delegate;
    float someDigit;
}

@property float someDigit;
@property (assign) id <ContentViewDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

ContentView.m

```
#import "ContentView.h"


@implementation ContentView
@synthesize someDigit;
@synthesize delegate;

- (void)handleContentTouch:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    someDigit  = 134;
    [self.delegate passDigit:someDigit];
}

- (void)setupView
{
    CGRect frame = self.frame;


    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleContentTouch:)];
    UIImageView *fifthBackground = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];
    [self addSubview:fifthBackground];
    [fifthBackground setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [fifthBackground addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}
```

MainViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ContentView.h"

@interface MainViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIScrollViewDelegate, ContentViewDelegate>
@end
```

MainViewContorller.m

```
#import "MainViewController.h"

@implementation MainViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ContentView *contentView = [[ContentView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    contentView.delegate = self;
}

- (void) passDigit:(float)someDigit
{
    NSLog(@"%f",someDigit);
}
```

Comment: Why didn't you just update your last question?

Comment: Because I changed it. Here im not using notificationcenter.

Comment: You didn't really change it; you just removed some text...

Comment: Did you implement the delegate method in your MainViewController?  If so, please post the contents of `- (void)passDigit:(float)someDigit;`

Comment: I mystakenly usethe name of my method. Now it's edited. The concole doesn uotput nothing. So passDigit: doesnt get called.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do, may be you are new and learning out some things. Try doing the following:

Change your method in mainViewController

```
- (void) showDetailViewControllerWithDigit:(float)someDigit
{
  NSLog(@"%f",someDigit);
}
```

to

```
- (void)passDigit:(float)someDigit
{
  NSLog(@"%f",someDigit);
}
```

and it should work. Also not very relevant here but you have spelled delegate and delegete in two different places. Be mindful that they both will be considered as two different variables.  Though not necessary to have an instance variable with the same name, I would definitely not have it with a slight typo, because it will cause a lot of problems later.

When you define a protocol for a delegate, the methods you have defined there should be implemented in the delegate class.

Also in your code you have, obviously you have missed some parts, which show as to where you are adding the contentView in the main view controller. I am assuming that some where you have

```
[self.view addSubview:contentView];
```

in the viewDidLoad or some where, without which you cannot even see the contentView and there fore cannot tap it.

Happy coding.

Comment: Sorry for my mistakes. In my class i have correct spelling, I make mistake when I wrote it here. I check the names and the passDigit: method doesnt get called. Where's the problem. I the view is added inside custom cellView. And I want access to it from MainViewController, which is subclass of UITableViewController. And I can see the view, and I recognize touch, I test it so there must be a problem with delegate.

Can someone tells me how would you access data the view from cellView.